# Questions about the definition of commensurate charge density waves in 1T-$TaX_2$ structures

Tags: waves, insulators, strong-correlated

I am reading some papers related to charge density waves in 1T-TaS2 or 1T-TaSe2, which are among the most studied systems with CDW and strong correlations.

I checked the definition: A CDW is commensurate if and only if the wave vector describing the CDW is a rational number times one of the vectors that make up the Reciprocal lattice of the crystal. In practice, the denominator of that rational number needs to be small, and the number needs to be independent of temperature.

However, the CDW superlattice in 1-TaS2 is the size of $\sqrt{13} \times \sqrt{13}$. I can't figure out how the CDW superlattice is defined as 'commensurate' since the reconstructed lattice can't be a rational multiple of the vector of the original unit cell.

The attachment is for reference: [Electronic correlation effects and orbital density wave in the layered compound 1T-TaS2](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.125138)

Comment: Well, 13 = 2*2 + 3*3 so now consider how that looks.

Comment: Or look at the Si $\sqrt{3}$ by $\sqrt{3}$ reconstruction.